# How to update a Swagger UI after a Liquibase Changelog was done

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, liquibase, springdoc-openapi-ui

I use `springdoc-openapi-ui` in my demo spring boot project. To play around with Liquibase, I created a dummy Entity

```
@Entity
@Table
public class DummyEntity {

// with field "dummyNumber" 
// with field "dummyText"
// with field "phone"
```

My Swagger UI works perfectly here.
[image: Swagger UI]

Ok, now I add a changeset to liquibase master changelog. Let say I add

```
//add column dummy_boolean
```

This also worked perfectly, after spring boot reboot I take a look into my DB.

[image: MySql after changeset was applied]

But the problem is, when I visit my Swagger UI again, there are no change its still the same. I understand that this Swagger UI is generated on my Entity Class but how I can solve this issue? I need to see the new column in my Swagger Ui also.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Swagger UI, but I did some googling using the terms you've used in your question and came across some links that might help: 
* [Swagger tutorial with entity](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/api-catalog/open-perm-id/permid-entity-search/tutorials/swagger)
* [Getting Started With Spring Boot 2 + Swagger + liquibase](https://medium.com/getting-started-with-spring-boot-2-swagger)